# How to get value of <td> on click which is created by php while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am retrieving 2 columns from database and displaying them in table. Now i want to give onCLick() on 1st column which is DesignNo. Now problem is that every td dont have unique id, so how can i get the value of td tag and call next script?

**Displaying Table**

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <th>Design No.</th>
         <th>Design</th>
     </tr>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td id="designno" onClick="SingleImage();"><?php echo $row['DesignNo']; ?></td>
            <td><img class="productimg" src="php/<?php echo $row['DesignImage']; ?>"></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

**SingleImage()**

```
        var date = document.getElementById("txtdate").value;
        var designno = document.getElementById("designno").innerText;
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = 'php/LineUpProductDisplaySingle.php';
        var params = 'date='+date+'&designno='+designno;
        http.open('POST', url, true);

        http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
           if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = this.responseText;
           }
        }
        http.send(params);
     }
```

Comment: `id` must be unique, change to `class="designno"`. How about passing DesignNo to the function? `onClick="SingleImage(<?php echo $row['DesignNo']; ?>);"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass `this` to the function.

```js
function SingleImage(elm){
  alert(elm.innerText);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Design No.</th>
    <th>Design</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td onClick="SingleImage(this);">A</td>
     <td>img</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td onClick="SingleImage(this);">B</td>
     <td>img</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this without inline event handlers defined in the HTML you could use `document.querySelectorAll` to target specific nodes in the DOM and then iterate through that collection and assign your event handlers. By removing the ajax code to a separate function you can re-use it to suit other requirements without needing to write the same its of code each time too.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

    var _ajax=function( url, params, callback ){
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if( this.readyState==4 && this.status==200 ) callback.call( this, this.response )
        };
        http.open( 'POST', url, true );
        http.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        http.send( params );
    }

    var col=Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('table tr td[2]') );
        col.forEach( function( node ){
            node.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                _ajax.call( this, 'php/LineUpProductDisplaySingle.php', 'date='+document.getElementById("txtdate").value+'&designno='+this.innerText, function(r){ document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = r; } );
            }.bind( node ),false);
        });
},false);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use duplicate id instead of class and assign class

> name='designno'

put below code in click event of 'designno'

try using jQuery

```
var design_no = $(this).closest('tr').find('.designno');
```